# Jquery remove append duplicate data

Tags: jquery, duplicates

i have manage to remove and repopulate the data, but sometimes it will duplicate my data, ive check that `info` does not contain any duplicate data until this part of the code runs. please advice.

tabbody - was my tbody which contain dynamic tr
info - includes all my tr and td datas.

javascript

```
        function UpdateCourseList(course, section) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'showServlet',
                data: {'course': course, 'section': section},
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    var template = $('#template').html();
                    var info = "";
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        info += Mustache.to_html(template, data[i]);
                    }
                    $("#tab1tbody").children("tr").remove();
                    $("#tab1tbody").html(info);
                    $("#myTable").trigger("update");
                }
            });
        }
                $("#tab1").on("click", "table #courses", function() {
                var course = ($(this).closest("tr").children("td").eq(0).html());
                var section = ($(this).closest("tr").children("td").eq(1).html());
                UpdateCourseList(course, section);
            });
```

mustache

```
        <script type ="text/template" id="template">
        {{#course}}
        <tr id="courses">
        <td>{{col1}}</td>
        <td>{{col2}}</td>
        </tr>
        {{/course}}
        </script>
```

html

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>col1</th>
<th>col2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tab1tbody">
</tbody>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in http://jsfiddle.net? It seems `info` is the culprit. Have you checked it's value?

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follow, There is no need another code

```
$("#tabbody").html(info);
```

And I am not sure about `$("#table").trigger("update");`. Can you give "update" handler definition?

Comment: i just use it from tablesort "update", without update it stops executing after the first click.

Comment: I believe that You add the button as a part of info. Use jQuery "live" instead of "click" or "bind". If I am wrong, edit your question with more javascript code.

Comment: sorry i do not know how to indent the code here. i use click to select my tr and fetch this data using ajax to do changes in servlet and display the new data, im quite sure my servlet does not have any problem as i have check there is no problem with my `data`

Comment: @user2863217 Can you Post rendered HTML of table on after page loaded? and POST definition "update" events callback

Comment: sorry, im not so good with my coding. I never heard of rendered function before. how do i do that?

Comment: @user2863217 No more sorry, I am asking about piece of code after your page load. I want to see the HTML source of "Table with id - myTable".

Comment: I have to look "td" structure and buttons with in it.

Comment: the td structure is in mustache with javascript, i dun have any button, whenever i click on tr, it will call #tab1.on(click)

Comment: @user2863217, Since "info" don't have duplicate, I guess your "UpdateCourseList" executed two or more times. Have u checked that how many times "UpdateCourseList" course executed on single click?. You can also check how many ajax request send for single "tr" click by using firebug or chrome developer tool. "$("#table").trigger("update");" in this "update" is custom event. "Update" should have some handler(callback) function. As I mentioned my answer, I need to look the definition of that handler function.

Comment: @user2863217 I hope that your problem isn't isolated from other part of your Javascript. So try to use of debugger, you can understand your problem better.